# TagHelper ; how to modify dynamically added children

Tags: razorengine, tag-helpers

The `asp-items`  Razor "TagHelper" will add an `<option>`  to a `<select>` for each value in the `SelectList`. I want to modify each of those children.

Specifically I want to disable some of them (i.e. add `disabled="disabled"`).

Even more specifically I want to dynamically disable some of them; I'm using angular so I could `ng-disabled="{dynamic_boolean_which_determines_disabled}"`. This means the option could be disabled at first, but after user makes a change, the option could be disabled (without page reload). Angular should take care of this; I think Angular and TagHelpers should work together in theory...

**I expected:**

I could somehow access an IEnumerable of the children `<option>` tags that would be created (i.e. one for each item in the `SelectList`), iterate the children tags, and SetAttribute("disabled") or SetAttribute("ng-disabled")...

**I tried:**

1. Creating my own TagHelper which targets the `select[asp-items]`, and tries to GetChildContentAsync() and/or SetContent to reach an IEnumerable `<option>` tags and iterate them and process each, but I think this will only let me modify the entire InnerHtml as a string; feels hacky to do a String.replace, but I *could* do it if that's my only option? i.e. `ChildrenContent.Replace("<option", "<option disabled=\"...\"")`
2. Creating my own TagHelper which targets the `option` elements that are children of the `select[asp-items]`, so I can *individually* process each. This works, but not on the dynamically-added `<option>` created by `asp-items`, it only works on "literal" `<option>` tags that I actually put into my cshtml markup.

**I think this'll work but not ideal:**

1. As I said above, I think I can get the result of TagHelper's dynamic asp-items `<option></option> <option></option>`, as a string, and do a string replace, but I prefer not to work with strings directly...
2. I suspect (I haven't tried it) that I could just do the work of `asp-items` myself; i.e. `custom-items`. But then I'm recreating the wheel by re-doing the work which `asp-items` could've done for me?

Comment: Just gonna mention [@Daniel J.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836935/daniel-j-g) because they seem to know a lot. But I guess "@"ing that user [may not work the way I expect :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 0):

So I hadn't yet read the "AutoLinkHttpTagHelper" [in the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#inspecting-and-retrieving-child-content) which uses string replacement (specifically RegEx replace) to replace every occurrence of a URL, with an `<a>` pointed at that URL. The cases are slightly different*, but...

Anyway, here's my solution once I learned to stop worrying and love the string modification:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("select", Attributes = "asp-items")]
public class AspItemsNgDisabledTagHelper : SelectTagHelper
{
    //Need it to process *after* the SelectTagHelper
    public override int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue;

    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#ProcessAsync
    public AspItemsNgDisabledTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator gen) : base(gen) {}

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        //Notice I'm getting the PostContent; 
        //SelectTagHelper leaves its literal content (i.e. in your CSHTML, if there is any) alone ; that's Content
        //it only **appends** new options specified; that's PostContent
        //Makes sense, but I still wasn't expecting it
        var generated_options = output.PostContent.GetContent();

        //Note you do NOT need to extend SelectTagHelper as I've done here
        //I only did it to take advantage of the asp-for property, to get its Name, so I could pass that to the angular function
        var select_for = this.For.Name;

        //The heart of the processing is a Regex.Replace, just like
        //their example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#inspecting-and-retrieving-child-content
        var ng_disabled_generated_options = Regex.Replace(
            generated_options,
            "<option value=\"(\\w+)\">",
            $"<option value=\"$1\" ng-disabled=\"is_disabled('{select_for}', '$1')\">");

        //Finally, you Set your modified Content
        output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent(ng_disabled_generated_options);

    }
```

}

Few learning opportunities:

1. Was thinking I'd find `AspForTagHelper` and `AspItemsTagHelper`, (angular background suggested that the corresponding attributes; `asp-for` and `asp-items`, would be separate "directives" aka TagHelper).

   1. In fact, TagHelper "matching" focuses on the element name (unlike angular which can match element name... attribute... class... CSS selector)
   2. Therefore I found what I was looking for in `SelectTagHelper`, which has `For` and `Items` as *properties*. Makes sense.
2. As I said above, I extend `SelectTagHelper`, but that's not *necessary* to answer my original question. It's only necessary if you want access to the `this.For.Name` as I've done, but there may even be a way around that (i.e. re-bind its own For property here?)

   1. I got on a distraction thinking I would need to override the SelectTagHelper's behavior to achieve my goals; i.e. Object-Oriented Thinking. In fact, even if I did extend `SelectTagHelper`, that doesn't stop a separate instance of the base `SelectTagHelper` from matching and processing the element.  In other words, element processing happens in a pipeline.
   2. This explains why extending and calling base.Process(), will result in Select doing its job **twice**; once when your instance matches, and again when the base instance matched.
   3. (I suppose could've prevented SelectTagHelper from matching by creating a new element name like `<asp-items-select>`? But, not necessary... I just avoid calling `base.Process()`. So unless that's a bad practice...)

*Different in this way:

1. They want to **create** a tag where none exists, whereas I want to add an attribute a tag **which is already there**; i.e. the `<option>`

   1. Though the `<option>` "tag" is **generated** by the `SelectTagHelper` in its `PostContent` (was expecting to find it in `Content`), and I don't think tags-generated-in-strings-by-content-mods can be matched with their corresponding TagHelper -- so maybe we really are the same in that we're just dealing with plain old strings
2. Their "data" aka "model" is implied in the text itself; they find a URL and that URL string becomes a unit of meaning they use. In my case, there is an explicit class for Modeling; the `SelectList` (`<select>`) which consists of some `SelectListItem` (`<option>`)  -- but that class doesn't help me either.

   1. That class only gives me attributes like `public bool Disabled` (remember, this isn't sufficient for me because the value of disabled could change to true or false within browser; i.e. client-side only), and `public SelectListGroup Group` -- certainly nothing as nonstandard as `ng-disabled`, nor a "catch-all" property like Attributes which could let me put arbitrary attributes (`ng-disabled` or anything else) in there.